# How to decode a Json with a root array?

Tags: scala, case-class, json4s, http4s

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to decode a `json` with a root array into a case class using `json4s-jackson` library.

The purpose of extracting directly into a case-class and not into a `Seq[Username]` is to validate the existence of a single value in `decode -> construction` stage, and not in a later time.

When the root is **not an array**, everything **works** perfectly:

Working example:

```
{
    "users": [{"name": "someName1"}]
}

case class Username(name: String)
case class UsersInfo(users: Seq[Username])

implicit private def reader: Reader[UsersInfo] = (value: JValue) => value.extract[UsersInfo]

def decode: EntityDecoder[IO, UsersInfo] = jsonOf[IO, UsersInfo]
```

---

**But**, when a json has a root array, it starts smelling bad:

```
[
  {
    "name": "someFancyName"
  }
]

case class UsersInfo extends Seq[Username] // Smelly & does not compile
```

Is there a "correct" way of decoding *root arrays*?
Is there **any** elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution may be validating decode result in the decoder function.

---

replace this:

```
implicit private def reader: Reader[UsersInfo] = (value: JValue) => value.extract[UsersInfo]
```

with something like:

```
implicit private def reader: Reader[Username] = (value: JValue) => {
  val extracted = value.extract[Seq[UsersInfo]]

  require(extracted.size == 1, s"UserInfo Json must contain a single username value, but it contains [ ${extracted.size} ] values")

  Username(extracted.head.name)
}
```